# Near-realtime satellite snow-cover imagery via easy web-interface

Tags: preparation, snow

I'm looking for a freely accessible website that provides access to recent high-resolution (<~1–5 km) satellite-based snowcover estimates (snow / no-snow). Many meteorology websites provide an interface to cloud cover satellite imagery, but it's not always easy to see snow-cover from those.

The *MODIS* satellite provides visible imagery down to a 250-metre resolution. This can (in absence of clouds) certainly be used for the above-stated purpose, and indeed they produce a [daily global snow-product](http://nsidc.org/data/modis/gallery/global_daily_snow.html) at a roughy 5 km grid. Although accessible in principle in HDF-5 format, it's quite a bit of work to download and read this data to see the extent of snowcover 50 km from home.

The [Senorge](http://senorge.no/) website provides a fantastic interface, exactly what I'm looking for, but only for Norway.

Many meteorological websites, e.g. SMHI in Sweden, provide regular [snow-thickness maps](http://www.smhi.se/vadret/vadret-i-sverige/snodjup), but those are heavily interpolated and irregularly updated.

Does anyone know a website that lets the user look at recent satellite-based snow products on an easily zoomable map? I'm most interested in Sweden at the moment, but it would be quite interesting if it was global (like the *MODIS* product).

Comment: I posted one answer, but I'm still open for better alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MODIS data is accessible as [JPEG images](http://lance-modis.eosdis.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/imagery/realtime.cgi).

Sometimes it's still not easy to find an exact point on the image, but at least you don't have to bother with HDF. If you can't find today's images for a specific region, you can look back in time.

We use this service to check ice coverage on big lakes when planning ski trips.

Answer (score 4):

[This NASA web-interface](http://neo.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/Search.html) provides a somewhat recent (several days old) interface to global daily snow-maps. From the main page, click on *Land* (immediately below the map), then click on *Snow cover* in the drop-down menu that appears. Then, on the right, under "Matching datasets", select "Snow cover - 1 day (Terra / Modis)" and click "Select". This will show a 3-day old global snow-cover map that is zoomable.

[image: NASA global snow-map zoomed in for Northern Europe]

This is the best I have been able to find so far. It doesn't show the coastlines, but in this example we can see the Alps, the southern Norwegian highland and a wide arch in Lapland and Finland. The resolution is not optimal and it's hard to see what is where.